# How to add Two auto-generated field in one model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am in need to create two auto-generated fields:
1st field is ID and I am taking the position that is equivalent to id or we can say it is also an auto-generated field in the model.

here is the code which I am integrating:

```py
class DeviceControl(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    position = model.[what do I write here to make it auto generated or equal to id]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: You mean `position` have same value when `id` is generated right?

Comment: if you need two fields always be the `same value` you don't need to create second field, because it's value will always be the `same as first field's value`

Comment: yeah exactly same i need with position

Comment: I need that because i want to do sortable so initially there value will be same but after drag to new position,  i will change the position accordingly. and id will get no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `save` method to set the initial value of `position`:

```py
class DeviceControlPolicy(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    position = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
       
       if self.position == None:
          self.position = self.id
          # You need to call save two times since the id value is not accessible at creation
          super().save()
```

Comment: May you please give little elaboration

Comment: @Mukul Instead of using a second auto field, you can use a simple integer field. When the model instance (database record) is first created, the `save` method set the initial value of `position` to the same value of `id`. Then when you want you can simple update the `position` value as you need without changing the `id` field. Under the hood the `save` method override the value of `position` if it's `None`, so during the instance creation it set its value to `id`.

Comment: @AlainBianchini An interesting approach, what about the performance of this? Are two separate database calls are made here? One for the initial `save` and generation of the `id`, and a subsequent call for the update of `position`?

Comment: @DanielZaksevski It's best to leave the management of `id` to the database to maintain integrity, so the only way is to override the `save` method or use a signal. With either method, however the database is used twice when the instance is created. Another solution (better for performance) would be to set the default value of `position` to `None`. If the `position` value is `None` then just check the `id` (if the value is `None` it means that `position` has never been changed and is therefore equal to `id`), if `position` has a value then it means it has been changed and you can simply use it